# GPOs not applying even after gpupdate /force....but after a couple of days, do apply

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2

For some odd reason, after I run gpupdate /force on both server and client, the GPOs do not apply. gpresult /r on the client does show that it recieves it and it is being applied but it does not do it: This is for network shares, scripts, automatic software installation, etc.

I also shutdown and restart the PC but still nothing. For obvious reasons, I cannot test the server being shutdown and restarted constantly.

But after a few days pass, I do see (for example, network shares) being applied and actually working.

As you can see, here is a Windows 7 PC after gpupdate:

[image]

This means it is being applied. Well, it was the exact same way when I made the GPO and it did not do those two until a few days passed...

Is there a reason for this? My domain controller is a Windows Server 2012 R2 and the clients being tested are Windows 7 SP1

Comment: Are you using security group filtering for applying those GPOs?

Comment: No. They apply to all users. Plus like I mentioned gpresult shows them being applied....but they don't do anything...

Comment: You are sure that you are not trying to apply user settings to an OU which contains only computers or the other way round?

Comment: That's one of the first things I usually check but no....

Comment: Sorry if *mi Espanol es malo* (my Spanish sucks) but there are a couple of things I'm noticing: First, you mentioned this is set as *user* settings, but your GPresults --> Configuracion De **Equipo** implies it is a *computer* policy (please correct my if I'm misinterpreting this). Secondly, is the GPO you created an actual option in Group Policy Management Console (GPMC)? I ask this because your Gpresult also says that your domain *type* is of Windows 2000 which probably does not have that option (I am assuming this because Win 2000 pre-dates Powershell),

Comment: Startup and logon scripts run at startup and logon, respectively. Software installation happens at startup or logon (if being assigned to the computer or user). Post screen shots (in English) of the Group Policy settings you're trying to apply.

Comment: @Get-HomeByFiveOClock I ment that it gets applied to the users thru their computer policies. Sorry for not saying that correctly. Also, the Windows 2000 is a known glitch. https://www.404techsupport.com/2012/05/why-does-gpresult-say-domain-type-windows-2000-on-a-server-2008-r2-domain/

Comment: @joeqwerty This was a example of a policy that is not applied after just a few days. It happens with scripts, registry settings, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Activate the GPO setting "Always wait for the network at computer startup and logon" (in Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\System\Logon). Once this has applied (can take a few reboots), all future GPO edits will reliably apply on the next boot.